# BSC Testnet addLiquiditiyETH TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

Tags: ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, hardhat, bsc

I'm coding an bep20 token and if I want to add Liquidity with pancakeswap I get the following error:
`ProviderError: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'`
Does anyone know why this is not working?

PancakeRouter address: `0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1`
PancakeFactory address: `0x6725F303b657a9451d8BA641348b6761A6CC7a17`

My addLiquidity function:

```
function addLiquidity() public payable {
        _approve(address(this), _pancakeRouterAddress, totalSupply());

        _pancakeRouter.addLiquidityETH(
            address(this),
            totalSupply(),
            0,
            0,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
```

Hardhat fork: `npx hardhat node --fork https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545`

Hardhat networks config:

```
networks: {
        localhost: {
            url: 'http://localhost:8545',
            chainId: 31337,
            forking: {
                url: " https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545",
            }
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure two things when you add liquidity which uses transferFrom() function internally:

- You have approved the spendor (here router)
- you have at least the amount you have approved the spendor to spend